# Show adding dates of files in a directory

Tags: git

I'm looking to see which files were added when in a subdirectory of git project. Looked at the man for `git log` but nothing jumped out as what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --reverse --diff-filter=A --summary <directory>
```

This will list the commits, starting from the oldest, in which any of the files in the given directory were created.

Comment: This worked for my needs: 'git log --reverse --diff-filter=A --pretty="%ad" --summary .'